# boto3 ses InvalidParameterValue error due to unicode characters

Tags: email, unicode, mime, boto3, amazon-ses

I am trying to send emails through SES using boto3. Below is my code.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import boto3

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['Subject'] = 'i am subject äöü'
message['From'] = 'sender äöü <from@email.com>'
message['To'] = 'receipient äöü <to@email.com>'
html = MIMEText('<strong>Welcome to AWS SES äöü</strong>', 'html')
message.attach(html)

ses.send_raw_email(
    RawMessage={
        'Data': message.as_string()
    }
)
```

But i am getting the exception below. This error is something to do with unicode characters(äöü) in `From` and `To` addresses. If i remove the unicode characters then email is sent successfully.

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the
>   SendRawEmail operation: Missing final '@domain'

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "InvalidParameterValue - Missing final '@domain'" from Amazon SES while sending an email with unicode characters in destination address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305454/getting-invalidparametervalue-missing-final-domain-from-amazon-ses-while)

Answer (score 0):

Encode the email parts as suggested in https://mg.pov.lt/blog/unicode-emails-in-python.html. This solved the issue and now i am able to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SES documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html):

> If you want to use Unicode characters in the "friendly from" name, you must encode the "friendly from" name using MIME encoded-word syntax, as described in Sending Raw Email Using the Amazon SES API.

One way to do it:

```
from email.header import Header

msg['Subject'] = Header('helloé éé', 'utf-8').encode()
# '=?utf-8?b?aGVsbG/DqSDDqcOp?='
```