# What does Amazon SES Error message: Missing '"' mean?

Tags: amazon-ses

```
Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidPara (truncated...)
 InvalidParameterValue (client): Missing '"' - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Missing '&quot;'</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>86fcc78e-4781-407c-b444-26f46a516958</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

The email was not sent. Error message: Missing '"'

This is the error i am getting !! and cant figure out the reason ..
Somebody give me a hint please

Comment: Just off the top of my head, it seems like you're missing a double quote character `"` in a parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means there is an encoding error while sending the request and is rejected by SES. Developer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html) will be helpful for you to find the correct encoding.

Related issue on github: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1196

Related question on SO: [boto3 ses InvalidParameterValue error due to unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291378/boto3-ses-invalidparametervalue-error-due-to-unicode-characters)

PS: I would have commented this, but I don't have the privilege :)